# Allow temporarily closing a question as "gotta be a duplicate"

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

One of the issues with duplicate questions is finding them. Sure, frequent users of a tag know most of the common ones. But there are plenty of questions which you *know* has to have been asked, but it's going to take you 5-20 minutes of searching to actually find it. During which time the question will be answered.

To prevent answers between the recognition of the question as a duplicate and providing the actual question it is a duplicate of, I propose being able to *preemptively* close the question as a duplicate. That is, you can vote to close as a duplicate without providing an actual question it is a duplicate of. After the question is closed, the appropriate duplicate will be provided later. Naturally, closing them with one vote would be given to [those who are worthy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer).

Once a question has been so closed, anyone with close-voting powers can provide the duplicate question. Unilaterally. The idea being that if the person didn't have dupehammer powers, but had voted to close as a duplicate of that question, the person who *did* have dupehammer power would just pick the question they cited.

To prevent the obvious abuse that this kind of closing can create, there should be 2 extra measures attached to the feature:

1. A timeout. If an appropriate duplicate has not been provided after 15 minutes, then the question is no longer closed. This should also bring the question back to the top of the homepage, as though it had been edited.
2. A penalty for failure. If you vote to preemptively close a question, and it is closed (either with our vote or via dupehammer), but the question is reopened before a duplicate is provided (either via timeout or explicit reopen votes)... every person who voted to preemptively close the question *loses 25 rep*.

The last one is there to make sure that you are *serious* about this form of closing. If you use this power, then you are betting your reputation that you or someone else will find that duplicate question within 15 minutes.

Oh, and the 25 rep loss should be uncapped. That is, losing it doesn't mean you can recover it just by getting more upvotes. So even Jon Skeet will suffer from this punishment. Granted, 25 rep is a rounding error to him, so he probably won't notice ;)

Comment: Yeah - I usually take the cowards' way out and shove a 'Too broad' or 'Unclear' close-vote on them.

Comment: It used to be fun to add cutom close-vote reasons like 'this has been posted more times than Sepp Blatter has offshore accounts', but then I just get flagged:(

Comment: I don't exactly think the rep penalty is a _bad_ idea, but do you think a hammer ban, analogous to a flag ban, might more appropriate? Or that could be in addition: screw up five or six times in a row, and no more Mjölnir for you for a couple of days.

Comment: I think there needs to be a better way to identify possible duplicates (other questions with matching keywords, that are often duplicated, or some other metric) and a way to list them when reviewing a question

Comment: Btw, if anyone knows the original "find missing integer in array" question among the 2662 search results, you can close this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600557/finding-the-missing-element-in-an-array

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, I would go one step further and propose that the duphammer be usable even without specifying a duplicate, now or in the future. Finding the duplicate target is then an exercise left up to the OP/reader, which will be good practice for them anyway. For others visiting the question, which is now marked as dup with no target, they can simply move on to their next search result.

Answer (score 8):

We don't really need this, and it seems like a lot of programming work for the devs just so a few questions get closed a few minutes earlier.

Duplicates of true FAQs don't last very long; people tend to jump all over them. For example, I can't speak for everyone, but I think many if not most of the moderators and dupehammer-wielders keep a list of common duplicate targets. (`<aside>`I use a text-expansion program, so I can just type a few characters and automatically get the right link for a dupe close vote. Obviously, that comes in handy for lots of other stuff, too.`</aside>`) So, when it really has been asked 1,743 times already, odds are good that somebody will be closing it very, very soon.

If "everyone knows" it's a duplicate but nobody has found one after 15 minutes, then either (1) the question isn't getting views for some reason or (2) it's unlikely it's actually a dupe.

Meanwhile, what's the harm? We want the site clutter-free, sure, but putting a possibly-good question on hold for 15 minutes while people *look* for a duplicate doesn't help anyone. It may turn out not to be a duplicate. It may get edited significantly before anyone finds the "right" target. Or the person who put the hold on it may wander off for a cup of coffee and forget about it. When that happens, the question just languishes for 15 minutes and gets shoved off of the homepage, but the OP has no idea why.

In short, I see this as a lot of work for the SO devs, but with numerous potential problems and very little upside.

Comment: The point is that, within that 15 minutes while the dupe is being searched for, the question can still be answered. The goal of this feature is to prevent that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand that would be the goal, but my argument is that this affects a pretty small number of questions. It would only matter if a dupehammer-wielder (1) saw the question before it was closed and before it was answered, (2) couldn't think of or find a dupe immediately, and (3) followed through on the promise to close the question as a dupe. Even then, it only matters if somebody else bothers to post an answer in the meantime. I just don't think that happens very often.

Comment: Just in the last few hours, there have been two cases where I immediately picked up a question and in the few dozens of seconds that I was looking for a dup it had already been answered.

Comment: @user663031, could be because new users want to grab a minimum of reputation, so they pick easy questions to answer. Flagging as duplicate isn't going to award them anything.