# Why are questions with silly errors well answered?

Tags: discussion, support

Stack Overflow is always known for quality questions. But you see there are many questions where there is a minor mistake or typo. Take an example of this, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564261/settimeout-to-remove-class-not-firing/43564290?noredirect=1#comment74179395_43564290

The question is now deleted but the mistake it contained was passing 10,000 instead of 1,000 to a parameter requiring milliseconds and wondering why it didn't fire after 1 second.

I have tried to raise the same concern in that question.
Then also such questions have answers as well as upvotes.

**Is Stack Overflow awarding reputation points for such questions?**

**But for what reason!!!**

Just to point out that the OP is missing a colon, an extra *s*, etc, etc...

*Neither do they help other community members in the future*.

Is there any rule to sort out this issue?

Comment: *Is there any rule to sort out this issue.* You can/should flag it as off-topic.

Comment: @MartinSmith I mean to say they get answers for a no cause \

Comment: The person with the accepted answer would have been on 39 rep at time of answering so couldn't comment if they wanted to and tbh I don't bedgrudge them trying to boost their rep. The 10ker could have voted to close as "simple typographical error" though. Closing questions doesn't give rep and answering does so the gamification incentives don't work towards that though. Chances are that the meta effect will cause it to be deleted anyway.

Comment: well that question got noticed However there are many which go unnoticed

Comment: Your claim is exaggerated, at best it is known for *surviving* quality questions.  Deleting the bad ones is unpleasant work with way too many candidates and far too few users volunteering to help with that.  We'll (probably) get rid of it.

Comment: I think there was a feature request to remove rep from answers that are later closed as typos.

Comment: There's a general one here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324430/should-answer-reputation-be-removed-for-closed-questions but I'm still sure there was one that suggested this for a specific close reason, not all of them.

Answer (score 7):

I agree this is bad, but currently our reputation system encourages this behavior:

- [Reputation motivated persons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore#comment915310_281787) get fast reputation points for answering this kind of questions with their [FGitW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)
- New users see, that they get an answer even for asking bad questions

As long as this is the case, the persons that care about the site quality are outnumbered.

The only way I can imagine, as I answered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324180/2441442), is to remove reputation from answers, that are closed. But it may have some side effects, as explained in the [followup feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324430/should-answer-reputation-be-removed-for-closed-questions).

Comment: I think there should be a seprate section in SO for new users,if they are not sure how to ask questions ,and feel that those questions are not going to help other members in future.

Comment: I disagree @Hemant. Sometimes we have new users that have great questions. Remember, we all started somewhere with zero reputation and have had our problems we needed an answer, that only Jon Skeet can provide. Instead of a seperate community we need to identify a way to improve the general quality of the site. Triage for example is failing dramaticly.

Comment: yes it they are worthy they can be added to the main queue.

Comment: who would decide this? The persons we lockout into a seperate community because they always ask off-topic question or the "expert"-community? If the latter, where is the difference to now? If the former, why should we trust them? @Hemant

Comment: what makes the strength of the site (open to all for asking/answering) also has it flaws, but changing that would be more detrimental. See expert exchange and their system: it's terrible.

Comment: @Pang thanks for the info. This meta post had escaped my notice. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I agree this is super-annoying and adds pollution to the site, along with "wall of code questions".

In that case, first thing to do is comment explaining the error to the OP so hopefully he/she deletes the question before it is answered & downvote / vote to close.

Once preventive measures have failed, downvoting the answer is sometimes inefficient, even if this is the first vote, because you always find a user upvoting just because the answer is "not wrong", not to mention it is not efficient at all after 1 upvote.

Flagging rarely works in that case either (although you can try it if the answer is very low quality like "I had same problem try add semicolon error go away")

So, yes, some user is gaining easy rep from typos questions, good for him/her, but I doubt the user can reach 20k with that kind of answers, so *let it go*.

(The only exception would be when the typo is "stealthy" and leads to a code working without error messages, but doing something unexpected. Those questions become interesting by accident, and they can at least help warn current readers about some language traps (like the famous comma in C).)

The most important is that the typo question recieves enough downvotes & close votes so it's deleted and it doesn't pollute the site anymore, so get close privilege and fight this with us.

Comment: I've seen some very high rep folks that shudder at the words "close vote". I dispute your claim that "the user can['t] reach 20k with that kind of answers".

Comment: ok he can reach 20k ... in 20 years :) as a low rep user, you may be tempted to answer bad questions to gain rep, but when you get more rep, you're fed up with that. That's not me who shudders: I vote to close very often, and since I have 1 gold badge, I use it a lot for duplicates instead of answering the same thing (which is also a source of pollution, vaguely related to the issue discussed here)

Comment: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)