# Disable hammering via voting to close if you have answered the question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I think you should not be allowed to vote to close a question you have answered.

Even if the answer is deleted, you still should not be able to vote to close, because you can just undelete the answer and get rep from it after the question is closed.

There is a loophole in the system that is being gamed more and more by those that should be working to make the system better, not game it.

I think you should be disallowed from voting to close for **any** reason if you have answered a question. And if you have a deleted answer it should be allowed to be undeleted if the question is closed so as to not allow retroactively gaining rep on a closed question. Especially duplicates.

See also : [Should I mod flag users who repeatedly answer a question and then vote to close it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355308/177800)

Comment: `There is a loophole in the system that is being gamed more and more by those that should be working to make the system better, not game it.` Can you show some examples of this malicious behaviour you are describing? Pretty sure I have done this in the past with dupe-closings, providing the OP with custom advice relating to their problem, but closing it as a duplicate because it *was* a duplicate. I don't see what's wrong with that.

Comment: If you are going to vtc, don't answer, imo. If you want to provide additional data do it either as an answer in the dupe target, or via comments.

Comment: What if you answer, the OP explains that you misunderstood and their question then becomes a duplicate of something else after the explanation. You can't then delete your answer and close as a duplicate?

Comment: If this is a loophole being gamed more and more you should be able to provide SEDE statistics to back up your assertion.

Comment: This would only reinforce users who actively choose to answer questions *without* using their close votes, and punish users for answering questions that they didn't know were duplicates before and now do for example. Given how fiendishly hard it is to find even the most obvious duplicates, this would be extremely counterproductive. There must be better, fairer ways of dealing with users who both answer and vote to close questions (in either order).

Comment: *There is a loophole in the system that is being gamed more and more* - how long has this been going on and how often are you noticing it... and if it's that big a problem, why can't I see (I've only gone as far back as May) any flag from you trying to point this out to the people who have the tools to address it?

Comment: I have a better idea. Nullify reputation from **any** post that gets closed in 24 hours for any reason.

Comment: @Antti and if it gets closed incorrectly and never re-opened? Can't help but feel that's going to confuse people and deter them from ever answering anything with even a single close vote just in case it does get closed. Then they'd have to go on a campaign (probably on meta) about getting it re-opened... Be great for drama - pretty lousy in practicality though.

Comment: @JonClements then they'd ask to *reopen* it, and write to meta. They would have a good *reason*. Why would you need reputation for answering *off-topic* questions?!

Comment: @JonClements Or... cancel the reputation from any *trusted* user answering questions that were closed in next 24 hours - with great power comes great responsibility. They would have an incentive to move their answer to the duplicate target too...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a real problem but if it needs numbers on how often this happens and by whom [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712185) might help. It shows the users that have both answered and dupe hammered a question. I guess the ones with an answercount of 1 are the ones you're question is about as that would indicate gaming?

Comment: @rene I am not sure how to read the results... :D

Comment: @rene ah got it, the answercount means avg number of posts to the answer.

Comment: @rene: I note that I'm high up there, as are T.J. Crowder and BalusC (but with different average counts). All three of us have also written a huge number of answers, and have a large number of gold tag badges; we have a larger number of dupe hammers than most (15, 25 and 30). I'm not sure if that's available, but how many of these duped posts have other close (dupe or otherwise) flags or votes on them, cast before the dupe hammer was applied? What are the *overall* dupehammer stats for these users?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was afraid someone was going to ask that. I silently hoped the low number of users involved would lead to a *meh, this is not a problem*. As I have to parse the text column of PostHistory it is a bit of a struggle to get the data you ask for. I'll give it a go for 6 to 8 minutes. Beyond that you'll have to contact Shog9 or Bluefeet to run a query on their internal SEDE which has a full normalized history.

Comment: @rene: I don't think it's a problem either; I think this is barking up the wrong tree. We have yet to receive a flag to substantiate a specific case. But if someone is going to try to dig up numbers, I want to make sure we look at the whole picture, and not just try to dig for proof of a hypothesis, only looking at numbers that fit a specific pre-conception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I manged to add a column that counts how often [the user was the first close voter](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712185). I don't have flag info in the public SEDE. Didn't make it in 6 to 8 minutes :(. Determine if they were the 2nd, 3rd, 4th or last voter requires so much sql fu that I'm going to leave that alone, also because that is error prone. But if someone want to give it a try, [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712186?opt.textResults=true) is a query to practice on.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Proposed on MSO [Should answer reputation be removed for closed questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324430)

Comment: @rene: does your script distinguish between standard answers and answers made as a community wiki? The difference is important, since community wiki answers wouldn't give the poster any reputation and so wouldn't be "gaming" the system (according to Jarrod, and whatever that means).

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter nope, it doesn't  but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't matter much. You can fork the query and add it your self by adding a where clause for communityowneddate is not null

Comment: @rene: maybe you could, since you understand how to do that junk, but I'm afraid I can't ;)

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter fair enough, updated the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dukeling is entirely correct in his answer that if the feature is implemented as you suggest, it would only ever result in duplicate questions not being marked as a duplicate, not in duplicate questions getting less answers that aren't adding any value.

Instead I'd propose that when this situation happens an automatic mod flag be triggered, since there's a pretty high chance that *some* action would be merited in this situation.  If the mod notices a pattern of this behavior from a user, they can notify them that they're doing something wrong, if the answer is of very low quality it can be deleted, if the duplicate closure was inappropriate the question can be reopened, and if the answer is useful and is adding value *above and beyond what's in the duplicate*, the questions can be merged, moving the useful answer to where it can be most helpful, to the canonical.

Comment: why force moderators do the remaining legwork of checking whether such flag is worthy or it's just a single occasion and not a pattern. Instead, system could do it automatically, eg by running (say weekly) job and reporting cases where particular user does this frequently enough to bother

Comment: @gnat The odds are quite high that the post merits some action even if there *isn't* a pattern.  Notice how out of all of the options I mentioned, only one of them mentioned doing anything if there's a pattern (and really that one applies *in addition* to all of the other reasons, not instead of).

Comment: I understand but without stats of how often this happens at all it's hard to tell whether this will work. If this happens, say, 50-100 times a day then load on moderators would be too high to meaningfully handle such flags (dealing with duplicates is often difficult) - in this case I'd rather let some of this stuff slip through. OTOH if there are like 10 times a day then 20+ mods can possibly manage it

Comment: Shoving it in the `VLQ` queue would be more appropriate than raising a mod flag. Either way this behavior has negative connotations.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson There's nothing to be done in the VLQ queue.  Even if the answer isn't a *useful* answer, it'll be *an answer*, which is all LQP is there to handle.  And there are enough situations that will require moderator attention that I don't see a reason to not just go right to a mod flag; it'd be so rare that non-moderators could clear up any given situation.

Comment: @Servy - I will defer to your judgement then, I have not visited any of the review queues in years ...

Answer (score 16):

For argument's sake, let's assume some people are gaming the system in this way.

If this request gets implemented, since they can now only do one, do you think they'd be more likely to close or more likely to answer?

I'm guessing they'd be a whole lot more likely to answer, and then the question might not ever get closed and the number of questions we should be closing, but aren't, increases.

---

The same argument applies to the case Mark pointed out - if a user is at first not able to find a duplicate and instead posts an answer, they'd be unlikely to later (delete their answer and) close the question as a duplicate (especially since users are unable to delete their answer if it's accepted).

Comment: While Mark's answer provides a good reason as to why this happens, this is absolutely the reason why this feature should not be implemented.  Rep hunters will hunt for rep no matter what - but if the goal is closing duplicate questions as duplicate, then don't force them to choose.  they will choose the wrong one 99.99999% of the time

Answer (score 10):

I occasionally do this (answering, then voting as duplicate), and you seem to assume bad intent where there might be none.

For example, sometimes I answer a question as I couldn't find an immediate duplicate at that time. Then after posting the initial answer, I want to add additional info for further clarification or writing the answer makes me think of better search terms, and then I find a duplicate. I then proceed to gold-hammer the question as duplicate and move on. I will not remove my answer, because it does answer the question.

If you assume this behavior is 'rep hunting', then you are wrong, because as soon as a question is closed as duplicate, the answers will usually not attract any more up votes, nor will they usually attract an accept vote.

(answer adopted from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355335/466862)

Comment: If you later realize the question is a duplicate when you didn't before, then why are you not deleting your answer once you realize it's not longer being helpful?

Comment: @Servy Uh, because the answer **is** helpful, frankly I am rather amazed at the suggestion that an answer would no longer be helpful if the question is closed as duplicate.

Comment: If the answer is actually adding information above and beyond what already exists in the duplicate, then it should be posted to the canonical, not the duplicate.  If it's not, then it's not helpful.  The only reason the answer would be helpful on the duplicate question is if the question isn't actually a duplicate, and the voting to close was incorrect.

Comment: @Servy sometimes it's not obvious that it's a duplicate. Duplicates _are_ helpful, if not too numerous (Jeff Artwood said that himself)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Duplicate questions *that are useful signposts to the canonical* can be helpful.  Of course the vast majority of duplicates *aren't* useful signposts, as they aren't any more discoverable than the canonical or other duplicates; note that it's not about how many duplicates there are, it's about whether or not that duplicate is a useful signpost.  Finally, even if a duplicate *is* a useful signpost, we still don't want *answers* on that duplicate, we want them on the canonical, because the whole point of the duplicates *is to direct traffic to the canonical*.

Comment: @Servy Who is this "we" you're talking about? As far as I am aware there is no such consensus.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The "we" is all of the people of this community who are interested in helping people find answers to their programming problems. 
 So why do you want answers that people are dramatically less likely to see when facing a particular problem?  The goal of the site is to create resources that allow people faced with a particular problem to find a solution to that problem.  Making it harder to find good answers to a problem by putting them on far less discoverable duplicate questions, rather than the far more discoverable canonical, does not serve that end.

Comment: @Servy Interesting, so because I disagree with you, I am not one "of the people of this community who are interested in helping people find answers to their programming problems"? Interesting position, but it actually invalidates your argument.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not saying that you're not interested in helping people find answers to their question because you disagree with me, I'm saying you're not interested in helping people find answers to their question because you're advocating putting answers in places that are objectively harder to find, rather than in places that are objectively easier to find.  If you were advocating a position that actually made finding the answer to a question *easier*, not *harder*, then you would in fact be one of the people actually trying to make answers easier to find.

Comment: @Servy And now you are putting words in my mouth (assigning an opinion to me), because I actually agree with you most of the way (hell, I probably spend most of my time on SO voting to close as duplicate), I just disagree with your notion that one should remove their answer after they have found a duplicate. That is in my opinion counter-productive as it waste time and energy spent answering a question, and an answer addressing a specific question (and not the canonical), might cover aspects that cannot immediately follow from the canonical, which may help others in the future.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If there's important information that is necessary for a quality answer to the question to be provided in the duplicate question and that cannot be presented in the canonical then the questions aren't duplicates, because the canonical doesn't, and can't, provide that important information that's necessary for a quality answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy When writing an answer, you can point out things tangential to the actual problem. The immediate problem - after answering - may have turned out to have been a duplicate, but there is added value because it is an answer tailored to the question. Deleting that answer 'just' because it is a duplicate would therefor destroy value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So you want to post an answer that doesn't answer the question, and instead provides tangential information.  That's not what answers are for.  If you want to provide tangential information, rather than an answer, then post a comment, which is the appropriate place for such information.  That you prefer to have duplicate questions answered repeatedly, where each person gets their own unique answer for every duplicate question, is contrary to the very idea of duplicates.  SO *isn't* meant to be a place where duplicates are answered again and again each time they're asked.

Comment: @Servy Where did I say that?! I say that if you answer a question, that the answer is tailored to that specific code, or you can make **additional** observations that add value. If - after having written and posted that answer - you then find a duplicate that covers the main problem, then deleting that answer destroys value. And to be entirely clear, I'm not advocating that duplicate questions should be answered again and again (you're assigning an opinion, again).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You don't need to destroy the content.  You keep saying that I'm telling you to destroy content every time I tell you that you should *post it in the appropriate place*.  If you want to add some tangential information that's not a part of the answer to the question, then post it as a comment, not as an answer.  Any information of value isn't destroyed, it's just where it belongs.  And you *did* advocate answering duplicate questions again and again.  You specifically said that you see value in having every single duplicate question given its own answer "tailored to that person".