# How to resolve: User with gold badge: Answers question, marks question as duplicate. Marked question has no bearing on question asked

Tags: discussion, abuse

In the past I tended to dedicate myself to one tag. That tag is not served by many users so one users bad behavior has an impact on that community as a whole.

Their behavior is this (lets call this user X): X provides an answer, then marks the question as a duplicate, invariably to one of their own questions. I find it strange that someone would provide an answer when they are going to mark the question as duplicate but the real issue and damage is that the question that they have marked this question as a duplicate of has little to no bearing regarding the question the OP asked. Generally it has a key component in the title, but aside from that there is almost no correlation.

Now we could theorize why someone would do such a thing, but this tag only having a few users that provide the majority of answers, this user seems to have a disagreement with another user regarding this tag (lets call this user Y), and in a few instances where Y provides an answer, X then resorts to this behavior to deny Y of what would likely be an accepted answer. Although this wouldn't be the only case, they would do this.

Also I've observed that this behavior tends to double the chance of upvotes. In once case (probably the OP) has upvoted the provided answer, then the answer to the linked question, and then followed up with a comment after reading though to the effect "That this isn't what they wanted". So it is a good point farming strategy. Some people are just happy to have what appears to be some effort.

I have flagged a few such questions, one was (years ago, same user) it was turned down, a recently flagged one was marked as helpful, and I still have an outstanding one on a different question in the queue.

Really these tactics are so blatantly inconsiderate I feel that a means of disabling 10k privileges should be considered. Is such a thing possible?

Also while rare, perhaps checking for similar farming (consistently provide answer then vote to close), or a high number of "vote to opens" against one users "mark as duplicate" or "mark as closed" votes as a means of feedback to those users that they may be being unfair.

Adding further insult to injury, this tag having few users, getting five open votes to reopen would be exceptionally difficult.

UPDATE: This question is marked as a duplicate. The duplicate asks "[Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate)" that question ends with "I personally don't see anything wrong with this, as long as the user isn't doing it for personal gain" this question is about a user who is not only doing it for personal gain but that the duplicate question, isn't even a duplicate! Where the linked question supposes that at least that was done correctly. This question then is about how to resolve a case of abuse.

Comment: Ok, so, someone dupe closed a question, and you disagree with said closure. Does that sum up your question?

Comment: In short yes. In long, I'm convinced that it is intentional behavior.

Comment: I'm sure it was intentional, I think what you're concerned with is whether or not said user is abusing their privileges, for one reason or another.

Comment: A relevant factor, in my opinion, is that he answers before closing. That's _not_ acceptable behaviour in my opinion (if you close as a dupe, especially if you can dupehammer, you should _never_ answer). I'd say that such cases should be modflagged.

Comment: eh, not necessarily. It's certainly possible to answer a question, and then later realize that there's a dupe out there.

Comment: That is, with knowledge and intent. If it were some mistake or difference in opinion I would not bring it up. Also the user Y (who I am not) has seemingly given up his resigned himself from grieving further, yet this sort of behavior I don't think should be tolerated.

Comment: Is X a gold-badge holder in that tag? In this case he should definitely never answer and close-vote on the same question.

Comment: @BDL He is a gold-badge holder.

Comment: Related: [*Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286072/2751851)

Comment: RE: "getting five open votes to reopen would be exceptionally difficult." I am not quite sure the reopen queue is filtered by reviewer tags. I am often presented with reopen reviews on tags I don't have a score with.

Comment: This is entirely too vague to stick a fork into.  Let a moderator figure it out, flag one of the questions you are upset about.

Comment: @duplode that is very related but even the answer explicitly notes that they are not supposing ill intent and thus that concern is not addressed.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier noted, however people who frequent certain tags tend to be experts in them, many questions only make sense to experts in that field and if one should re-open or not requires scrutiny that might not be available. Knowing if a question should be closed, seems easier than knowing if a question should be re-opened. Also I might be mistaken, but in the case of abuse, the OP may not edit the question and the question will only be moved to the re-open review queue if edited correct?

Comment: Oh, wait, it is RC.  He has graced meta pages many times before.  The mods know him well, ask them to help.

Comment: @HansPassant ... I thought X was better but yes. He was banned once... but again there aren't so many people in that tag, a ban isn't ideal. But some fang-extraction is clearly required (10k and gold badge privileges in his hands are a menace).

Comment: Also I flagged a few things but without this meta, I don't think there is proper context from what I was seeing. Is there a way to call on mod without using a flag to explain things, that is the only reason I created this meta question. If I could have done all this behind the scenes that would have been ideal. Maybe I should have tried chat...

Comment: SOCVR is also an option in that case. I asked for their help in 2 particular similar occasions, and that ended not so well for the gold guy.

Comment: @Quaternion I don't actually think this question is a dupl\*cate of *Answering a question, then closing it as dupl\*cate*, and I haven't voted to close it. The close voters have picked [*Disable hammering via voting to close if you have answered the question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355334/2751851) as the target, which I don't see as a dupl\*cate either -- that question amounts to a specific feature request that you haven't suggested at all.

Comment: @duplode I agree however I did find them interesting, also that last one points at:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355308/should-i-mod-flag-users-who-repeatedly-answer-a-question-and-then-vote-to-close which is pertinent to the behavior. Frankly I would be happy to close this question. I don't like negative comments about others to float around for all to see for all time. This is an exceptional case, if you agree and think something will be done let me know that you registered a close vote and I'll throw mine in too.

Comment: @Quaternion I think the question you have just suggested is an appropriate target, and have voted to close against it. As for "[if you] think something will be done", if you believe there is a widespread problem here you might want to consider making a feature request out of your suggestion of "a means of disabling 10k privileges".

Comment: @duplode I would rather not. Given that I am less than 10k I think it would be seen as sour grapes. If someone else were to do so I would happily upvote them. I clearly see at least one case where "de-fanging" (remove 10k features and gold badge features for reasons of abuse), would be appreciated by a few people.

Comment: @Quaternion On "sour grapes", I don't think that should stop you -- primarily because that would be a silly reason to disapprove of an otherwise well-formulated feature request, but also because there are many sub-10k users who are both active on Meta and knowledgeable about the site. (By the way, you aren't far from 10k either...)

Comment: I've done so, please feel free to edit as you know my intention: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364694/feature-to-remove-benifits-to-10k-users-and-gold-badge-users-for-reasons-of-abus

Comment: @duplode I posted it an within a minute have a -3 score =) an issue too is not having mod tools my language might not be correct as well.

Comment: @Quaternion Well, whatever the reason, it's true that Meta gives downvotes like candy =)

Comment: (Another note on Meta behaviour: proposals to rein in power user tools often get a frosty reception. I feel the main reason for that is content curation being perceived -- not without reason, I'd add -- as a hard and thankless task, specially in the busier tags. FWIW, [my one feature request of this sort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336788/2751851) was very carefully worded, and even so the reaction to it was, at best, mixed -- it is also interesting to have a look at the fate of the somewhat more blunt answer it got.)

Comment: @duplode oh no issue, I actually was thinking the same thing, and what prompted the "Well, that escalated quickly" comment. Also I know I posted a bit too hastily... but even a more more carefully crafted question would have likely met the same fate, although it probably wouldn't have crashed quite so spectacularly. I've never had a question with that sort of reception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166929/discussion-between-quaternion-and-duplode).