# Feature to remove privileges from 10k users and gold badge holders due to abuse

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-tools, abuse

This feature request is to provide the option to remove 10k and gold badge privileges. I see this feature as not being less than a ban, it should only be considered when considering a ban as an option. And should only be available to elected moderators. Thus most users should feel rather safe that this isn't something that would *ever* apply to them.

The feature flow would go like this: if a user is about to be banned, the moderator handling it should ask themselves the following questions:

1. Is this users ban a result of abusing their 10k moderator privileges or gold-badge privileges?
2. Is this user providing useful contributions to the community such as questions and answers, and not engaging in communications abuse?
3. (If the answer to the two previous questions is "yes":) Would you consider, removing moderation features as an alternative to a ban?

I think the above questions make it clear when such a feature would apply (whether it is practical or not to actually implement that way is another matter), and that while rare it does provide a means of reducing the loss of content from what might otherwise be a useful contributor.

This stems from a recent question/issue, if you are so inclined you may search for it should you need context.

Comment: Moderators can already 0 out an account, temporarily if need be, how does this add? And again, what would initiate such action? A flag from a user?

Comment: what abuse of [10k mod tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) are we talking about? because just from my understand the only abuse i can see is spamming incorrect delete votes and flag resolutions

Comment: Moderators already can deal with such accounts. We can suspend someone for abuse, for longer periods if they don't improve. In extreme cases, we can have accounts deleted entirely.

Comment: Few people push it that far. The number of troublesome 10k+ accounts that need repeat suspensions is still *very, very small*. We don't need new functionality to handle them.

Comment: The issue in question is a tag with a low number of users can have a gold-badge user mark questions as duplicates, while providing an answer, and in this case link to questions that are certainly not duplicates. While this is annoying the tag does stand some benefit from this user.

Comment: The issues are caused by abuse the gold tag badge affords.

Comment: @Quaternion: so **flag such abusers**, so we can handle them.

Comment: @Quaternion gold badge privileges != 10k mod tools from my understanding

Comment: @MartijnPieters There might be a meaningful difference between an outright ban and privilege removal -- the latter would not stop the affected users from asking and answering. The cost-benefit considerations with respect to implementing it that you mention still apply, of course.

Comment: On a tangential note, I don't think such a feature, if available to elected moderators only (i.e. folks that most likely know what they are doing), would require an elaborate dialog like the one you describe.

Comment: @duplode I did make a note in the next paragraph that the dialog is more a litmus test for my intention, rather than what need be implemented.

Comment: @duplode: again, the number of actual abusers is way too small to expend effort on removing features. And actual abuse of a feature like is means there is a lot more wrong that just removing of a feature won't solve. Just letting such users continue to post questions and answers will lead to *more issues*, because they are no longer acting with the community interests at heart anyway.

Comment: @Quaternion I have edited that passage in an attempt to make that clearer.

Comment: @duplode thank you, I don't know what I expected but my sentiment is: Well, that escalated quickly. https://goo.gl/images/UeE43h

Comment: I see no escalation, only discussion and folks voting their opinion on this proposed feature. Meta seems to be working appropriately here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a reasonable stance. (I'm now thinking of Wikipedia and their complex system of disciplinary sanctions -- perhaps too complex for their own good.)

Comment: Is there a sudden outbreak of madness amongst gold-badgers?  Why do they need culling?  Are they infectious?   Seriously though, is this an actual problem at all?  Is it so widspread that specific action is required?   Are there many examples?

Comment: @MartinJames I think this is irony, I hope so anyways. The question regardless of it being considered bad or good, I hope it is clear that it is _really_ narrowly applicable. A feature that would only be applied when considering a ban - it probably is not applicable to +99% (of the over 10k group or gold tag badge holders), for which that is roughly ~3%(?) of SO as a whole. My motivation for the proposal is another matter, just wanted to clarify this detail as it might account for why the question is so popular (well unpopular).

Answer (score 21):

If someone is abusing their 10K/gold badge privileges, *they need to be banned*. Whatever the quality of their posts, they are clearly acting against the interests of the site and should be removed in accord with their infraction.

It doesn't matter which parts of being a member of this community you're violating. If you're violating them enough to be sanctioned, then you need to be *fully* sanctioned.

Comment: I'd say a ban is a bit too harsh. The usual would probably apply: start with suspension, then longer suspension if continued misuse, and almost never ban.

Comment: I had it pointed out that review-bans are an example where there is a system to temporarily remove a feature being abused. In the case that prompted this question, a feature of being a gold tag badge user is to blame. The user is hardly perfect but it's kind of like the "peter principle", his promotion has turned a compulsion towards gathering reputation into a problem (promotion leading to failure).

Comment: This tag has a small user group and he has provided quite a number of good answers. Since this feature seems to be an issue for this user, gaining it but not being able to remove it ironically will lead to another suspension or worse.

Comment: I wouldn't mind an answer along the lines of: "It isn't feasible to implement given the small number of users that this issue applies to; while more finesse regarding the issue wouldn't hurt we must use the system available which allows us to 0 rep, suspend for a period, or ban.", as these other methods are available such as zeroing, and to suspend this answer seem needlessly harsh.

Comment: My unwillingness to accept this answer also has to do with: 1) I honestly don't think the user can help it. While SO doesn't bear any responsibility for such, I feel that this user would take a ban/suspension rather harshly this section of SO Survey may be pertinent: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-disability-status 2) It is with regards to the value the user has contributed and weighed against issues caused to that tags community, which is sever annoyance but the proposed solution is a "lets keep making lemonade" kind of deal.

Comment: People I think see question as something that can be taken away, it is the exact opposite, it's a means of keeping a contributer where otherwise you wouldn't be able to. They have proven to be a bit annoying, but who's perfect.