# Is it bad form to answer a question and mark it as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just noticed myself answering a question, then someone suggested a duplicate, so I Gold badge'd it. This kind of a feels a little sticky.

Should I have:

- Deleted my answer?
- Have looked harder before answering?
- Or just leave it, as it's acceptable?

The extenuating circumstances are, this question was asked by a very novice user, the duplicates I found were kind of noisy, and so was the duplicate I ended up flagging.

The answer I gave was direct and provided more specificity and documentation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Similar discussion: [Disable hammering via voting to close if you have answered the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355334/disable-hammering-via-voting-to-close-if-you-have-answered-the-question)

Comment: This is a question of: what do you yourself want to achieve? There is *nothing* wrong with what you did. However: it will *look* very wrong to people who don't take two seconds to see what's up, and you may get nagged. A downvote or two, some accusing comments... Maybe even a meta post dedicated to your horrible act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is OK to close a question as a duplicate after someone else shows you that a question you answered is a duplicate.

Ideally,  you would then move your answer to the FAQ pointed to. Unfortunately,  SE has no mechanism for moving one of your answers. If you copy your answer from the duplicate to the FAQ, the moderators will be automatically notified of the duplicate answer,  and one of them will tell you off. This happened to me.

SE *still* needs better support for curation of FAQs.

Comment: I really don't understand your use of the word _FAQ_ here. What have Frequently Asked Question to do with this?