# Let's make it okay to answer THEN mark a question as a duplicate without closing the page. Let me explain how/why

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

This is not a rhetorical rant, this is an earnest scream for reform.

Sorry, I tried to make this as short as possible, but it is kind of a complex change that I am suggesting.  I probably left out some vital pieces why trying to keep this small.

Why do questions marked as duplicates need to be closed if [Jeff Atwood says](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/#:%7E:text=One%20thing%20I,this%20exercise?):

> One thing I want to be clear about, though, is that **duplication is not necessarily bad**. Quite the contrary — some duplication is desirable. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find the answer they’re looking for. And isn’t that, really, the whole point of this exercise?

Let's focus on "isn't that, really, the whole point of this exercise?".  This incredulously points to a personal and overdue revelation that I've had about what Stack Overflow should be -- "a researcher's paradise".

Right now, Stack Overflow is NOT a researcher's paradise and it doesn't appear to be on a path to this utopia either.

Put yourself in the mindset of a careful researcher:

- Researchers do not care about housekeeping.
- Researchers do not care how old a page is that gives them the best possible advice.
- Researchers do not care who the user is that gives them the best possible advice.
- Researchers want to find the most appropriate page as quickly as possible.
- Researchers want the fewest number of comprehensive pages that most similarly pertain to their problem.
- Researchers want answers to be unique, correct, peer vetted, and ideally be as few as necessary without leaving out any relevant insights.

Let's be perfectly honest, there is a review/curation bottleneck because the number of motivated volunteers with the permission and ability to do these tasks is fewer than the number of users who creating new content.

From what I see, the regulars in SOCVRs are doing a crazily disproportionate amount of the curation work.  The bright side of this is that many of the curators there are SMEs in their respective field, qualified to make decisions with very high accuracy, and there is an ever-present, self-scrutinizing culture in the room to keep people honest.  Even still, we are trusting a very small cohort, they are woefully outnumbered, they are often negatively labeled as gatekeepers, buzz-killers, narcissistic sheriffs, etc., and occasionally the targets of malicious voting which can skew the perception of good content.

So I am here today to see if I can sow the seeds of a new direction so that:

- duplicate (clear, complete, on-topic) question askers:

  - can still receive answers that are specifically tailored to their question AFTER being marked as a duplicate
  - will be given no guarantee that their question will have a long life on SO
- answerers who are unaware or don't care about the importance of curation can:

  - happily flit from question to question and fire answers as they please without being chastised
  - potentially earn rep points in a Stack Overflow where virtually all new questions are duplicates
- answerers who ARE aware and DO care about curation:

  - can still effectively mark duplicates without being cursed by the previously mentioned group
  - can ethically answer a question THEN mark it as a duplicate in one fell swoop without closing the page
  - don't have to spend 10 minutes looking for duplicates before allowing themselves to answer
  - will trust that a Duplicate Questions review queue (I have been thinking of it as "The [Gallows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallows)" while brainstorming, although it's not a very cheerful term) will see the most appropriate handling of the page.

Before I talk about The Gallows, let's talk about why SO isn't on the right path.
Currently, SO has a tradition of honoring older content even when the older page *isn't great* for a number of reasons (vague requirements, no mcve, no proof of research/effort, outdated accepted answer, misinforming vote tally / accepted answer, and more). Some people hold the belief that great answers make a question great -- let's agree to disagree on this.  New pages never get a chance to build up their own value because they are closed.  I see a protectionist culture that is akin to religions.  But science exists in stark contrast -- it perpetually puts itself under new tests and challenges so that it can only evolve into its most refined form.  *This* is **the whole point of this exercise.**  Why not let the new pages *challenge* the old pages for superiority?

Let's not worry about protecting the oldest pages that have such a gargantuan number of redundant answers that pagination is required.  Let's instead, try to build a "***researchers first***" culture to content curation instead of "***elders first***".

So, what will be the purpose of The Gallows / Duplicate Questions review queue?

This will behave differently to other queues -- this will be for SMEs / gold badgers in the tags of the questions. It will rely solely on the volunteers who have proven themselves to be knowledgeable and trustworthy.  I am SUPER flexible on the actual functions and algorithms to be implemented but the general goal is to give reviewers the opportunity to review, say, 6 questions at a time which are marked as duplicates then vote on which pages:

- are legitimately NOT duplicates and should be ousted from the aggregate
- add absolutely no new value to SO and should be outright deleted
- are most suitably merged into another page instead of being deleted
- should be found first by researchers because they are ideal questions with the leanest, most helpful, most comprehensive, and ultimately most researcher-pleasing (all other non-deleted pages in the aggregate would point to the highest "ranked" page)

Right now, this job of aggregating, comparing, closing, finding the "best" dupe target is being done in a non-democratic way and it can lead to other volunteers calling foul play.  By forging a new review queue, the responsibility for curating the best possible pages will be cast to many.  For SMEs, this might be just the new and exciting activity that they have been secretly yearning for -- something with real lasting purpose.

This is careful work and there is much to contemplate with this venture. I can think up at least one very predictable and concerning possibility:

### What if someone finds a popular page with 40 answers, studies them all, boils down the insights, crafts their own beautiful/narrow/complete question, then posts ~5 answers which eloquently conveys all of the correct/available techniques, even offers technique comparisons, and then marks their own page as a duplicate of the 40-answer page?

1. On one hand, the new poster might be hissed and booed by onlookers who see this as overt theft/plagiarism/poaching and wish to see it stomped out.
2. On the other hand, the new poster is making life SUPER easy for researchers because the entire page has been crystalized and educationally laid out.

Would our community react to this with disgust? Should it?  Might there be any protections/precautions regarding this scenario?

In the end, the new duplicate would be judged on its merit in The Gallows where it would likely be the clear "winner" in terms of total page quality.

Can you imagine a Stack Overflow like this?  What concerns do you have?

Oh, and because I didn't explicitly state it, I am suggesting that a page is never "closed" for being a duplicate.  Pretty controversial, eh?!?

And one page can be marked as a duplicate of 5 other pages (of which maybe none of them were marked as duplicates previously) and ALL of them would be included in the aggregate to be reviewed. (easier curation)

For the record, I have read associated pages such as:

- [Disable hammering via voting to close if you have answered the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355334/2943403)
- [Should I mod flag users who repeatedly answer a question and then vote to close it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355308/2943403)
- and more

Comment: Another related post: [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286072/11682469)

Comment: Thanks Jeanne.  Yes, removing the "closing" factor of marking a duplicate removes the bad smell of answering and marking a duplicate.

Comment: "Researchers do not care about housekeeping" Huh?

Comment: They don't care about the process of housekeeping/curation.  They just want good customer-facing product provided to them.  Many industries are this way. @MisterMiyagi  Even in basic web development, users want to find exactly what they want in 3 clicks or less.

Comment: You might want to consider using a different word than "Researchers", then. This one cares about housekeeping of information *a lot* – even if it just means that I *can* find what I want in 3 clicks or less.

Comment: they need to be colsed, so that we have not 666 canoncal threads for every idea

Comment: @nbk the Gallows is the solution for "executing" the worst pages in the aggregate -- only the best survive.

Comment: Wording aside: I'm not quite sure what this changes compared to the current means. As far as I can tell, this boils down to Badgers/SMEs deciding amongst themselves which Q&A to be canonicals, closed, deleted. That seems pretty close to what Baders/SMEs *already* do via various, less formal means. (I might just have missed the important pieces – the post is rather long.)

Comment: "no proof of research/effort". Some of those post are the best posts here. There's a reason we shouldn't care about that, and it's the fact that other users want to do the same thing, so "How to iterate an array in JavaScript" is a great Question, no matter the research effort. The more that's put into such a Question, the less valuable it becomes. When I want to do this and search for it, I don't want to hit a highly specific post where the Answers only focus on that very specific issue.

Comment: @Scratte _"Some of those post are the best posts here."_ These posts role model the idea that no effort is necessary (especially when the question has hundreds of upvotes) -- this is very confusing to newcomers who show no effort and get downvoted.  How long is `How to iterate an array in JavaScript`? Do you think researchers are happy to wade through pagination tabs-worth of answers that were already covered?  It is the page bloat that hurts SO.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not advocating to ask the Question again. Once or twice should be plenty. Truth be told, I have no issues with 40 Answers on those. I'll try them out and find whichever fits me best. I skip the ones I already tried that are mostly identical to a previous one. On the topic of "These posts role model the idea that no effort is necessary" which is my point. It should **not** be. Curating content on the basis of the effort is not good for the site. If a Question isn't here, is should be posted and kept. Not closed due to "lacks focus" as a proxy for "lack of effort".

Comment: I generally like your idea about reviewing duplicates as a group instead of single posts individually. But this bit about effort have me on the fence. The research that I do when I read through 5 duplicate is kind the same as you've mentioned. I boil it down to what I find are the best ones. With the current setup, I just can't tell others, except for voting on them. And in some cases it's bits from one Answer and bits from another, which makes it impossible to convey to others via votes.

Comment: @Scratte then don't get hung up on the effort thing -- that is such a trivial/passing aspect that I could be just as happy to have that edited out of my question.

Comment: You have some interesting ideas, but I think your proposal is a bit too radical, so it's understandable that it's getting mostly negative feedback. FWIW, my initial reaction was to downvote, but after reading your post I have enough sympathy for your suggestion to refrain from downvoting. OTOH, I'm still a *long* way from upvoting.

Comment: As that old blog article by Jeff Atwood points out, dupe questions aren't *intrinsically* bad. It's the dupe answers scattered all over the place that cause problems. Ideally, all answers to a question should be in a single pool where they can be easily found, and where they can be sorted by votes, and by date. OTOH, with ancient "dinosaur" questions containing numerous highly upvoted and possibly outdated answers, it's not possible for new answers to compete on a level playing field. Hopefully, the initiative to deal with outdated answers will partly alleviate that...

Comment: Okay, let pick something tangible. Google "php array of dates" then click the top result on SO. For me it was a page with 26 answers.  It was closed by another page with 11 answers.  That dupe target is linked to 22 other pages; some of which are dupes.  When does SO begin to design a way to consolidate much of its redundant content?

Comment: @mickmackusa Problem with consolidating is that apparently "we want to reward question askers", so simply merging obvious and simple duplicate questions, where value of the question itself is zero, would inevitably upset too many people. I propose that we remove rewarding questions altogether (we should still use votes to rate the content) and maybe we could end up with more organized, focused and less duplicated content.

Comment: That sounds like a problem we can fix with the tools we already have... @DalijaPrasnikar: Then you're taking away one of the few ways beginners can earn reputation.

Comment: @Cerbrus Problem can be with deleting some valuable answers in the process. If we could only merge without moderators, that would be nice.

Comment: Valuable answer != "redundant".

Comment: @Cerbrus I know... but question is do they really need reputation... I know this might be controversial opinion, but if it is possible to use the site even without having an account, then reputation alone if you just want to ask questions is not extremely relevant.

Comment: The old guard will not be around forever to curate.  People burn out, they go away, they even die.  Stack Overflow will need to replenish the pool of curators by allowing them to earn rep.

Comment: They need reputation to comment, among other things. We get people asking Meta how to get started earning rep almost on a daily basis.

Comment: Ever seen a page with 8 FGITW answers all saying the same thing within 60 seconds?  This is not valuable to researchers -- it is a waste of their time.  But we never kill the redundancy off because it is within a tolerable range of time.  This does not put researchers first.  A dupe closure would do nothing to stop 8 people all answering at the same time.

Comment: @mickmackusa: And that is ___exactly___ why we __need__ dupe closures to prevent new answers from being added. You have no idea how many obvious JS duplicates I have hammered before those FGITW answers came flooding in.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know that system built around reputation itself is far from perfect, and my proposal is just more of "we would need more thorough and structural reorganization" to fix all that is not working well. Don't take it too seriously...

Comment: Mate, this is the internet. I can't smell whether or not I should take your comments seriously, @DalijaPrasnikar. If I see a bad idea in a comment tree I'm involved in, I'm gonna respond.

Comment: _"You have no idea how many obvious JS duplicates I have hammered before those FGITW answers came flooding in."_  ...neither do you.  Honestly, I probably hammer about 20 questions per every 1 that I can actually answer (it might actually be more than that).  I am not trying to soften SO.  I am trying to make it better.

Comment: [I have a pretty good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus?tab=votes&sort=closure). My point is that the dupe hammer is a ___very___ powerful tool to prevent FGITW answers to obvious duplicates. Your suggestion completely removes that functionality.

Comment: Page not found.  My point is, you don't know how many FGITW answers would have been posted, because you already closed the page.

Comment: That link is linking to my close-vote summary, which only I can see apparently. Even if I only prevented _one_ answer for each dupe I hammered, I'd call it a win. I'm absolutely certain that the real number is higher, knowing the [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: I am not different from you, @Cerbrus.  I hammer as well as I can, as quickly as I can, for the same reason that you do -- protecting SO from needless bloat.  But this is not scaling well enough.  And this is burning out the finest of us.

Comment: ... And your suggestion is to remove the "closure" aspect of dupe closures. Do you see why I have problems with that suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion stops the futile attempt to stop duplicate questions from being posted and speed answerers from stopping the Roomba from doing its excellent work.  I am saying let people frenetically post garbage and give us a new tool to consolidate the masses of redundant pages so that can throw out the unnecessary content easily and democratically.  This way we don't have to look down at new users as "infidels" who are only here to wreck our beautiful garden.  My suggestions doesn't try to "stop loads of answers to simple obvious duplicated questions", it allows the new to challenge the old.

Comment: _How_ does it stop loads of answers to simple, obviously duplicated questions?

Comment: @Cerbrus " If I see a bad idea in a comment tree..." Absolutely. I am just saying that my suggestion is not full fledged proposal from my side and that I am aware that any changes in such direction would require other deep changes. But, whether we like it or not, reputation while it enables people to curate content, is also main drive that makes curation harder.

Comment: _"it allows the new to challenge the old"_ Then you'll be absolutely flooded by loads and loads of new duplicated answers that just re-hash the same solution time and time again. That's not "better" than how it works, now. It's worse, as we can't put a stop to obvious dupes any more.

Comment: We are already flooded with this content.  This doesn't change anything.  My suggestion allows new content to potentially outperform old content which has been immortalized despite the very likely possibility that the old content had a much lower quality standard.  Ever see any of those answers from 2008 where the answer is a single function name that is a hyperlink to the documentation?  Not helpful to researchers.

Comment: For the umpteenth time: Your suggestion is taking away one of the tools we have to reduce the problem. Your suggestion doesn't change anything about how "new content" is viewed or voted on. Your suggestion doesn't consider that search engines will still show the old question first.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Concerning "we want to reward question askers" or not: Asking a *good* question is *hard*. It definitely deserves a reward, and perhaps even a (much) larger one than answering. What might be worth changing is perhaps *how* questions are rewarded but abolishing question rewards seems very similar to abolishing duplicate closure...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I know that asking good question can be hard. But, how many really good questions are out there? And then we have issue with two line "canonicals" that are hugely upvoted and in reality don't deserve such reputation. If I really have the problem, then getting answer is reward enough. If  I am posting self-answered question, then I am interested in getting reputation from the answer, not the question itself. It is complicated...

Comment: I don't see how posting good new answer on old question prevents that answer to outperform old answer. It just takes time. And even if you post it under new question, it will require time for both question and answer to gain some traction. You have much better chances to gain visibility when posting on old highly active question if your answer really has something new and valuable.

Comment: If you post your new answer on an old page that has 4 pages of pagination -- good luck getting attention on your buried insight.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I don't see how any of that is different for questions versus answers. My most upvoted answers were written because *I* wanted to know the answer – answering was the most important reward *for me*. Reputation should indicate how much of the "for me" content is actually "for everybody", and that applies to both questions and answers. If someone writes a question in a way that makes it useful to others, that is worth *more* reward than just getting an answer. Many two-line canonicals are worthwhile because they are useful in general, not some specific corner-case.

Comment: If a question has 4 pages of answers, it probably doesn't need _another_ answer.

Comment: Probably, but not a certainty. Languages are making improvements all the time.  This isn't four pages deep, but it shows how hard it is to unseat an old top answer when a language improves itself. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348205/2943403

Comment: We also have good questions that have for some reason attracted more bad content than good content -- this is definitely not good for the researcher experience.  Virtually any new duplicate question with correct answers would be better for researchers in this case.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255281/2943403

Comment: @Cerbrus And if it does, it probably also needs a dozen deleted

Comment: And your suggestion is to just post a duplicate question. That's not _better_. We need to be able to un-pin accepted answers and then let the votes talk.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't think those questions illustrate your point well. Yes, reputation wise, your answers have a long way to go, but they are definitely not deeply buried.

Comment: You're also illustrating some problems here that your feature request _doesn't fix_. Throwing a review queue at a problem isn't a good solution, the review queues in themselves are flawed already..

Comment: When a page gets to 100 answers, there is probably either a question that should be re-asked into smaller niched criteria or the question was too broad to begin with. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325/2943403 This is not ideal for researchers or curators.  I sometimes sift through these pages and blow my whistle at redundant answers, but this is more tedious than I like.  And yet, pages like these are preserved as a catch-all canon to close with.  So when a new question is closed with this one, the asker is like -- thanks, I wanted to read a novel. :\ Not a good experience.

Comment: _"When a page gets to 100 answers"_ Please, link us to _one_ other question that got close to that kind of traffic. Preferably less than 5 years old. And even on that old js question you linked, the top 3 answers are perfectly fine. No "researcher" should have a problem getting an answer there.

Comment: Pfft. So I present a good piece of evidence (a page with over 100 answers) and it's not good enough?  I have to find another one?  And it has to be less than 5 years old? Why?  I am not saying that the top 3 answers are not fine.  I am saying researchers are overwhelmed by the content, there is likely to be redundant content, and the bloat is not helpful to the researcher experience.

Comment: You just linked us to the [tallest man in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wadlow) and are basing your feature request on that specific case. Edge cases don't make good policy. Just because _you_ may be overwhelmed by how tall Robert was, doesn't mean we all have to start walking on stilts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026069/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109022/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/2943403 ...I'll leave you to peruse the rest of the search results using `answers:100..`

Comment: Every single one of them is ___old___, and has gotten a _lot_ of traffic. Your suggestion is to toss that all in the trash and copy the top 3 answers to a new question. For the last time, _How is that an improvement_?

Comment: There is no pleasing you.  Why is age relevant?  Researchers don't care how old a page is.  They just want _unique, correct, peer vetted, and ideally be as few as necessary without leaving out any relevant insights_.

Comment: Because you still haven't answered how your suggestion makes anything "better".

Comment: Because old questions just become persistent buckets as a catch all that researchers have no interest in wading through.  A new question which would normally be closed as a duplicate of the massive one, might actually have a much more narrow focus and invite a much better page than the old canon because it doesn't suffer so much unsavory bloat.  But we'll never get to a Stack Overflow like that because we close down duplicates instead of giving them a chance to survive by their own merit.

Comment: There's a distinct difference between "researchers" and "developers looking for answers to problems." A researcher probably _does_ like a lot of answers. Better for statistical analysis and other scientific methods. Users looking for an answer to a problem, otoh, would prefer to find "the" answer "they" need at the top of the list. This proposal might make things better for researchers. It wouldn't make it better for the target users, or the site's presumed mission.

Comment: You keep repeating assertions about "researchers" having trouble finding an answer, but your suggestions don't make that any easier, as there will be _more_ duplicated content. But that's a comment I've already stated multiple times in here... In essence, this whole comment thread is similar to what your suggestion would result in. People repeating the same things over and over again. I've also never heard of people finding it difficult to find answers in the context of there being __too many__ answers... Usually those complains are about broken search.

Comment: There will not be too many duplicated pages, there will be "enough" -- the Duplicate Questions review queue would be in place to democratically remove duplicate pages without losing any value from the site.  (that would be the mission anyhow)  I am willing to suggest new potential solutions, instead of just saying oh well, SO isn't great, but it's the best we have.  We are putting too much burden on the few curators that we currently have.  An those curators to frequently hated for the good work that they do. Oh, and I am not saying I want to "trash" 100-answer pages.

Comment: No, _another_ review queue isn't a solution. It's just shifting the problem elsewhere. You're putting _waaaaay_ too much faith into reviewers.

Comment: another review queue might not be _the_ solution, but it is certainly _a_ solution to the fact that a single gold badger can unilaterally close a page, then with the assistance of 2 other high reppers, delete the duplicate.  This is fine when it is right, but not fine when it is abused.  I am asking for a more systematic and democratic approach to curation that is more inviting to those who otherwise pay no attention to curation.

Comment: How does a review queue prevent an "undemocratic" approach? You can easily ask your friends to vote a certain way... You can just link to a review.

Comment: The new queue doesn't need to behave like the other queues.  Notice that I said that it was for gold badgers.  It could also be structured like the elections here.  You can vote, the voting can be open for a length of time.  Once a minimum quorum is satisfied, then tally all of the votes for certain actions.  As I said before, I am flexible on how it is designed.

Comment: Strongly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-vote

Answer (score 30):

> Let's instead, try to build a "researchers first" culture to content curation instead of "elders first".

No, we're not here for researchers, we're here for developers. We're building a repository of *Quality Q&A*.

> What if someone finds a popular page with 40 answers, studies them all, boils down the insights, crafts their own beautiful/narrow/complete question, then posts ~5 answers which eloquently conveys all of the correct/available techniques, even offers technique comparisons, and then marks their own page as a duplicate of the 40-answer page?

That's almost literally plagiarism, and [definitely not okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/1835379).
Instead of 40 answers on 1 question, ranked by *years* of votes, you now have 45 answers on 2 questions, where the newer one has no votes to distinguish bad answers from good ones.

[image]

Who's to say that one user is right in their chosen 5 answers?
What would prevent some other user from adding yet another answer to those 5, because he thinks the 5 existing answers aren't good?
Why would that one user be allowed to get all the rep?

---

All in all I'm seeing a lot of assumptions in this feature-request-discussion, quite a few of which don't fit the SE/SO format.

**The whole point** of dupe closure is two-fold:

1. Point the reader to an existing question that has the answer.
2. Prevent duplication of content by preventing more of the same answers.

Take away point 2, and you're spreading out information. This means that finding that one good answer is now a "needle in a haystack".

Comment: _Who's to say..._ - everyone is free to vote appropriately if the answers are not helpful.  If another user wants to add a sixth unique answer, then good.  The new user should get any rep that is earned.  Assume they put in hours of excellent work.  Would you feel differently if they posted a single, multi-faceted answer?  This could be a condition.  Bear in mind, there is nothing stopping another user from posting a newer, better answer in the future.  All of which will be reviewed in the Gallows.

Comment: The old, vote laden page is not necessarily lost/deleted.  The UI still points to it.  Regarding `1.`, we would still point people to duplicates. Regarding `2.`, if the new page brings nothing new/valuable to SO, it is executed by the Gallows.

Comment: I don't see how this suggestion improves anything... You're just duplicating more content, and the suggestion completely removes the _one_ feature we have to prevent duplication, ___especially___ on obvious duplicates that often get multiple answers within minutes of the question being posted

Comment: Also, completely unrelated, but should I read your name as _"Mick Mack USA"_ or _"Mick Mackusa"_, @mickmackusa? Or just "Bob" :D

Comment: "Narcissistic Self-righteous PHP Sheriff" seems to be my preferred handle on SO.  Right now, I am able to modify dupe linkages as I please -- this is not democratic.  And if I can get two other people to agree to a page deletion, it is gone in a flash.

Comment: On "completely unrelated" I always read it as "MickMacKooSa". Like Micheal Jackson's [MaMaSe MaMaSa MaMaCooSa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJlB06VYq1A) :)

Comment: If you must know, Mick is short for Mickey and my namesake is Mickey Mantle since dad is a diehard Yankee fan.  Mack was chosen over the common family name Malcolm because it too closely reminded people in my racist hometown of Malcolm X.  So yes, I've heard Mick Mack paddy wack give a dog a bone.

Comment: Well, technically I didn't ask for a backstory xD

Comment: My point is "programmers" are the "researchers".

Comment: I'm not seeing the suggestion as "spreading out information". I see it more like a "review duplicates as a group" where one can determine what should be kept and what is redundant. If a new post consolidates Answers into a better fit, some of the other Answer/Questions will become redundant and can therefore be removed.

Comment: @Scratte: But the suggestion also suggest leaving everything open to be answered, so there's nothing stopping the redundancy from growing again. It's also not closing the "source", so now you have answers in 2 places instead of one...

Comment: Yes, I guess I'm trying to look at the best part of the suggestion ;) But in my defense, sometimes posting a new better Answer is just preferable to fixing old ones.

Comment: It isn't plagiarism if you "boil down the insights" and use that to write your own answer. Of course, any text or code that *is* literally quoted does need to be attributed properly.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Maybe it's not _literally_ plagiarism, but I know I'd be pretty annoyed if someone took (a large part of) an answer I've written, and used that to re-post a new canonical. Even with attribution, you're just literally copy-pasting an answer to a new place where the author gets nothing out of it.

Comment: Hopefully, if the new author thinks your answer is good enough to be worth recycling in their answer, they'll think your answer deserves upvoting. And new visitors *may* follow the attribution link back to the original and vote on it.

Comment: That sounds like a chinese-made knockoff to me. They get all the money (upvotes), and someone that likes it enough _might_ come by and look at the real thing. I don't see how that's "better" than what we have right now. I mean, you can argue against my use of the word "plagiarism", but it's not exactly improving the OP's suggestion...

Comment: **1.** Oh, I'm not a fan of the OP's suggestion, but I think it's interesting food for thought, as I indicated in my comment on the question. **2.** Plagiarism is a pretty serious thing, so I don't like people throwing around the term lightly.

Comment: @PM2Ring: _"In the same vein, if the post consists almost entirely of copied work without original work, even if attributed, that may also be cause for removal (answerers should use their own words, quoted material should only be there to support the answer, not be the answer). See the help center on referencing."_ ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/1835379)). I've updated this answer to reflect it's not exactly plagiarism.

Comment: _"We're building a repository of Quality Q&A."_ my suggestion does not deviate from that goal, in fact, the purpose of this discussion is seeking ways to do it better.

Comment: I'm not saying your suggestion deviates from that goal... I'm saying that the sentence I quoted is incorrect. Don't take my words out of context.

Answer (score 5):

There's sort of another solution to this - though it's probably equally messy.  In the old days - community wikis were designed to be a sort of canonical/community built base of answers. While I'm not a fan of the way it was used, I feel like the 'idea' of a community built.

The 'standard' Q&A set has one selected answer, and should a dupe have an answer of value, it's 'lost' in a dupe closed question. If you *know* a question is a duplicate, and the answer is useful it belongs on the main question. The only way to 'move' an answer is merger and mergers are destructive and very scary.

But what if - we could have canonical wiki posts as the main post, and nondestructively add or remove existing answers to it?

Your 'new' post can be answered - and through some process (gold badge? Part of the dupe close process?) and link/fork the answer, nondestructively to a community wiki post. The owner keeps attribution, we can keep all the answers of value in one place, while a new poster can get an answer specific to their issue.

Of course there is a lot of details there, but that's one way to deal with it.

Comment: At least the original answer's author gets full credit instead of _"Made by Bob"_.