# Is this kind of question allowed?

Tags: discussion

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863012/appending-data-into-a-string-from-two-asynchronous-functions-in-node-js) involving a misunderstanding of how `setTimeout()` works in Node.js was posted.

Though the question is very basic, it seemed both on-topic and clear to me so I provided an answer. For me, the clarity came from this sentence: *"I want that test should return "Hello World" but it is returning empty string"*. The OP stated their expectation, showed a minimal reproducible example and then included what is happening instead.

Another similar answer was posted. Then, within minutes, both our answers were downvoted multiple times and the question got a couple of close votes for needs details or clarity.

Am I missing something here? Is this kind of question not allowed on Stack Overflow? Are answers to this type of question not appropriate?

Comment: It's (imho) not off-topic, but certainly not high quality. Sounds like a problem for me that should arise several times a week, are you sure that their isn't an easy to find duplicate for it?

Comment: It is a duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) and [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) and dozens more around asynchronicity. How many of these do we really need?

Comment: It's one of the most, if not *the* most, commonly duplicated question in [tag:javascript]. I'm ... surprised you're not aware of the duplicates.

Comment: Considering that neither of the close votes cast on the question at hand at the time of asking here on meta are for being a duplicate, it seems like the question here is still quite valid. I think it being a duplicate is a perfectly valid point and reason to close but the close voters should have voted that way, not as "unclear".

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't surprise me that there are duplicates, but finding such a duplicate that explains this specific problem in a way that is easy to understand for a newbie that offers a specific solution is not always easy.  If the question was closed as dup, I wouldn't have posted an answer.  But, none of the close votes were dups.  And, why the downvotes on people providing answers?

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to downvote answers to questions that they think are incomplete or duplicates as a way to say "you should not have answered this question".

Comment: @VLAZ - I don't necessarily agree that making it a dup of [how to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) is all that helpful.  This is a very basic misunderstanding of how `setTimeout()` works.  That specific issue is NOT explained in that other question.  So, while they are the same generic topic, it's kind of like telling a kid who has problem with a homework problem to go read the text book - the answer is in there.  It doesn't really answer their question or solve their problem.  IMO, that question is used far too often in this way.

Comment: @Catija - Ahh, they're too lazy to leave a comment or find the dup themselves?  So, they drive-by downvote instead and think that's helping things?  Is that how we want the community to work?  Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I've long been a proponent of recognizing that things like what you said in your comment just above, directed at VLAZ does seem "wrong"... to me, personally. I don't like the idea of saying "This is answered in a compendium answer that's three pages long, go dig through the answers to find the specific solution to your problem. I'd much rather have more bite-sized answers to specific, narrow questions... but my feelings on this don't direct the behavior of this site (or any site) - these sites are community-led and we can't (and don't) manage all responses.

Comment: In my dreams, I'd really love to find better ways to address situations like these. True duplicates, where the questions are both the short, concise problem do make good duplicate targets. I am completely on board with that. It's only where we expect askers to dig through long answers that I disagree. I was told to do that with my only SO question ever and it wasn't helpful because the duplicate and resources didn't answer my question in a way I could digest as a programming novice. I think there's a happy medium between no duplicates and duplicates that aren't specific enough. :)

Comment: @Catija - Thanks for the feedback.  While I've been around SO for a long time, the place still baffles me at times and the only real way to check if you're thinking about things appropriately is to see what others think.  That's for the thoughts.

Comment: That the OP needs more help than the duplicate can provide isn't necessarily evidence that it isn't a duplicate, more, that the target maybe is too broad for the given example. My reasoning for unclear rests exactly in the question you asked at the top of your answer: you're unsure of what help the op actually needs, and therefore we can't really discern which duplicate would be the most useful for this user without getting more information. Maybe promises would work for their needs, but without more info... we can't rule out that it doesn't actually need to be synchronous.

Comment: It's well established that [voters absolutely should not be downvoting answers to "bad" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459) (questions that are duplicates, unclear, otherwise low quality, etc.) solely based on the question itself. Downvotes are not punitive, and they should never be used this way. And yet... it does happen, unfortunately.

Comment: And there are dozens upon dozens of questions about this. With dozens upon dozens of answers. Take your pick for the best one and link it. It's an extremely common question asked multiple times a day in various forms. Do we really need 300+ new answers a year for these? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of SO?

Comment: @zcoop98 - That's a very interesting reference.  I particularly identify with [Brad's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/816620).

Comment: @VLAZ - A perfectly targeted duplicate with a bite-sized answer that is easy for a newbie to digest and understand would be just fine (if someone found one).  But, if you don't have one of those or don't quickly find one, how is a focused, on-target, very specific answer to the question being asked going to hurt stackoverflow in any way.  If that same thing happens 300 times a year, how is that hurting SO in any way?  The questions are there already (and won't stop coming).  It's just a matter of whether there's a specific, focused answer for the question or not.

Comment: @VLAZ - I'd argue that is actually helps SO more than sending the OP to some generic answer that is like telling them to go read the textbook to find the answer and they will end up feeling like they weren't really helped or worse yet, they will feel the hostility that lots of newbie users feel on SO.

Comment: "*But, if you don't have one of those or don't quickly find one, how is a focused, on-target, very specific answer to the question being asked going to hurt stackoverflow in any way*"  makes it even harder to find a duplicate in the future. Literally the purpose of SO is to provide common place for all the answers. Scattering them all around is exactly the opposite of that. Creates chaos. Hurts searchability. Goes against the reason to look on SO for answers. Because you cannot find them.

Comment: Instead, they were bombarded with a bunch of async/await and promise answers that, due to lack of info, noone knows if they're even relevant to the problem they're trying to solve. and, of course, all of those answers exist a few hundred times already. Maybe they've already seen them and deemed them not useful? Are we to assume the OP did no research?

Comment: @VLAZ - It sounds like you're arguing that having more answers makes it harder to find an answer to a question.  I don't understand how that works.  By your logic, SO would be a lot more valuable if lots and lots of answers were simply removed.  What SO needs is more high quality answers and less low quality answers.  SO isn't harmed in any way by adding more high quality answers that address a specific question being asked.

Comment: The OP has now responded that promise.all was what solved the problem for them. How were we to even know they had multiple promises, given their example? This is precisely why I didn't close it as a dupe. You're just throwing darts at a dart board.

Comment: @VLAZ - Closing as a dup of a generic question that doesn't address the specific issue asked is what does harm.  That doesn't answer the actual question asked.  It creates another search hit for something doesn't answer the actual question asked.  It frustrates a new user because they posted, got closed and didn't get an answer.  Further, downvoting quality answers for this reason just alienates people who provide quality answers (which is an important resource for SO).

Comment: "*It sounds like you're arguing that having more answers makes it harder to find an answer to a question.*" did *you* find an answer to OP's question? Did OP? Would future visitors? When they have to sift through *hundreds of answers* that are out there? "*By your logic, SO would be a lot more valuable if lots and lots of answers were simply removed.*" most definitely. There are plenty of duplicate answers. Scattered all around. If you have *fewer places to look at* with *less repeated information* it would be easier to find and evaluate the correct solution. Or am I wrong?

Comment: "*Closing as a dup of a generic question that doesn't address the specific issue asked is what does harm.*" again - take your pick for a more relevant answer. The question is not new. It's been answered again and again. I do not see why that needs to be the case, though. Why repeatedly provide the same answer? That's *not* what a knowledge base is about. I don't go on Wikipedia to find a dozen different articles on poodles. I want to find one, with all poodle-related information gathered there.

Comment: @VLAZ - You seem to be assuming that all answers that could possible answer a question are completely sufficient for all possible readers.  In practice, that's not the case at all.  Everyone has a different slant to explaining it and everyone attacks the solution differently.  The answers are all different.  Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71863110/816620) and [your suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)?  These are very different things, targeted at explaining things very differently.  SO is a better place if both of these exist.

Comment: "*You seem to be assuming that all answers that could possible answer a question are completely sufficient for all possible readers.*" I'm saying that we need *less* places to look for answers. Not more.

Comment: @VLAZ - As you well know, SO is not a manually curated, edited repository like Wikipedia.  The two simply don't work the same way at all.

Comment: @VLAZ - And, I'm saying that more specific answers to specific questions are more useful than pointing someone to a textbook of an answer and that SO is more valuable if people can find both kinds of answers.

Comment: "*SO is more valuable if people can find both kinds of answers.*" except they cannot. With hundreds of questions and answers scattered around, how do you find the correct answer? You don't. Just like you didn't. Just like I didn't either because at this point I can't be bothered to. Because there are just too many answers. The system is broken and by all means seems unfixable, too since apparently a fix is unwanted. You said it yourself - why find an answer when it's more convenient to write one. It's more convenient because answers are unfindable.

Comment: i mean, do we just stand in the way of helping people, while not fixing the system, to just leave it broken because noone with the ability to do anything about it appears to care that it's broken? At least if we treat it like a help desk, as occurred in this case, people get help... sometimes

Comment: @VLAZ - So if I can't find an answer that actually answers the specific question being asked in a way that I think will be useful to a newbie, it's better to link to a generic textbook-style answer that won't really help anyone?  That's the part of your argument I'm not buying.  Yes, it is difficult to find perfect duplicates on high traffic topics.  Should I refrain from helping someone because of that?

Comment: Step one should be requesting clarification when it's unclear why they're asking such simple concepts, rather than begin with just blanketing the problem with all the possible solutions. all the answers received in this case is no better than the mega dupe.

Comment: @KevinB - I agree if the question is unclear, but that question was not unclear.   They provided a problem description, a minimal, reproducible example and an expected result.  That is WAY more than many questions provide and is everything that SO requires. Several of us posted answers that took their code and showed them how to modify it to get the expected result.

Comment: There is no need to fight, guys. jfriend00 provided a clear answer that is useful for a newbie while no one else ever did and we ended up with only generic textbook-style answer that won't really help anyone. But since this answer now exist I'm sure it will be used as a dupe target and the "generic textbook-style answer that won't really help anyone" excuse won't be used ever again.

Comment: "*So if I can't find an answer that actually answers the specific question being asked in a way that I think will be useful to a newbie, it's better to link to a generic textbook-style answer that won't really help anyone?*" again - I'm saying we need less places to look for answers. Because that's what SO is *for* - looking for answers. It needs not be a single place. But we don't need new ones all the time because then searching for answers is impossible.

Comment: @Tom - Actually, I think VLAZ and I are discussing a point of some disagreement among power users on SO.  The generalized version of the question is "How closely should a duplicate match the question being asked to be marked as a dup?". When in doubt, I err on the side of helping the OP more specifically.  VLAZ wants to err on the side of having fewer answers to search through.

Comment: @Tom "*But since this answer now exist I'm sure it will be used as a dupe target*" keep dreaming. There are *hundreds* of answers on the topic. Nobody is using them as dupes. It's just another answer that will sink in the swamp of unsearchable, unfindable, and thus useless knowledge. That nobody bothers with because there is just so much of it.

Comment: Well, I guess my sarcastic comment wasn't as clear as I hoped it was :D. jfriend00, your argument why you chose to answer already proves VLAZ point. You're obviously not the first person to answer such a question for a newbie and there aren't only "textbook-style answers" out there, you either just assumed it is the case due to previous searches or you searched and couldn't find any good answers (I don't want to assume that it was just an excuse to not bother to search in the first place). Both proves VLAZ point.

Comment: Thanks to the "feels a bit as Clickbait"/non-Descriptive Title ("*Is this kind of question allowed?*"), I "probably"([sic]) found a "Duplicate"...: 
[Q: Are these sorts of questions allowed?](/q/293795/)... Oops...

Comment: Generally, it's a big problem that SO has a bunch of supposedly "canonical" duplicates that are in fact not of very high quality, but often ridiculously up-voted still. It's very hard to get people to let a good question with obvious duplicates "simmer" for a while, in hopes that a better answer than any already present on the site appears. It might be that the old "canonical" should be closed as dupe to the new question instead, if the new question attracts great answers. Otherwise we can never improve the quality of the site but are forever stuck with whatever is regarded as "canonical".

Comment: Oh...!?, @Lundin, my previous Comment was meant a bit sarcastic/ironic, I had not even checked the Content of the Qt I linked to only because it used the same (fairly vague) Title, and it ironically contains/quotes "*Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*"), ... which both didn't really apply... And I guess I was probably the first one ever to search the Site/Meta using "this+kind+question+allowed", which are all too broad Keywords... A Thread/Qt you are obliged to first open and read the Content before you can decide if it's relevant to your Search doesn't have a good Title...

Comment: One of the problems with the many duplicate (beginner) questions is that the answers are in most cases subpar. And the search engines for some reason pick the questions with non-comprehensive answers. And they are usually incomplete (not sufficiently comprehensive). At the very least there ought to be references (in comments or posts) that point towards the canonical question(s), but those references are usually *completely* absent. The rep hunters are not interested in this. Those that "just want to help" ought to include those references (they don't have a conflict of interest).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Sub par in what way?  If they offer a clear, specific answer to the exact situation that the beginning asked about and the canonical answer does not offer a specific answer to the exact code/question asked about, how is that sub par?  Canonical answers, somewhat by definition, attempt to teach a concept and show one specific example (targeted at the question they were written as an answer for).  They never show a specific example for the new beginner question.  So, I don't see how you can say these other answers to a new question are usually sub par.